# CIFilter shrinks resulting UIImage

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimage, cifilter, shrink

I know there is a bunch of threads about that subject, tho it reduced the transparency, but still it exists.

**Note, the UIImageView has a green background, which we SHOULD NOT see**

Original and filtered(guess who lol):

[image]

Code used (partial):

```
 blurFilter!.setValue(val, forKey: "inputRadius")
        
        if let output = blurFilter?.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage {
            let cgimgresult = context.createCGImage(output, fromRect: inputImage.extent)
            let result = UIImage(CGImage: cgimgresult)
            imageView?.image = result

}
```

**Note : If possible, i'm looking for the most efficient method in terms of runtime**
Any Suggestions? Thanks YOU!